# 500 internal server error in connection string on Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-2014

can someone guide me on this. I have to classic VMs(Application server and Database Server) on Azure. I have a asp.net web application connected to the database server and its working fine. But I needed to install a sql server 2014 on Application server and place a connection string for it in my web application. I have installed sql server 2014 on my application server and restored a database, but as soon as I place a connection string for the newly restored database in my web.config file, I get a 500 internal server error. As soon as I remove the connection string for newly restored database, the application works fine with the rest of the connection string.

Comment: what does inner exception say,also if i recall correctly,there is a setting in asp.net which will show detailed errors,you might need to look at that

Comment: FYA,install SQLServer and iis on same box is not a good practice